# SQL Oracle Date issue: ORA-01722: invalid number

Tags: sql, oracle

Wanted to have the date format as DD/MM/YYYY

I used:

```
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'MM/DD/YYYY';
```

Now when I write the line:

```
INSERT INTO staff Values ('ST01', 'Mrs', 'Katie', 'Elswood', '06/10/1990');
```

I get the error:

> ERROR at line 1: ORA-01722: invalid number

Any ideas whats wrong? thanks.

or i get the error message not a valid month?

```
STAFF_ID                                  NOT NULL VARCHAR2(6)
TITLE                                              VARCHAR2(20)
FIRST_NAME                                         VARCHAR2(20)
SURNAME                                            VARCHAR2(20)
DOB                                                DATE
ADDRESS                                            VARCHAR2(50)
HOME_NO                                            VARCHAR2(20)
MOBILE                                             VARCHAR2(20)
EMAIL                                              VARCHAR2(30)
NI                                                 VARCHAR2(9)
SALARY                                             NUMBER(13,4)
EMPLOMENT_DATE                                     DATE
BRANCH_ID                                          VARCHAR2(3)
POSTCODE                                           VARCHAR2(8)
POSITION                                           VARCHAR2(30)
TOWN                                               VARCHAR2(30)
```

Comment: Perhaps one of the non-date columns is a number.  Or, you could have a trigger that generates the error.

Comment: The ORA-01722 error isn't related to the date column (though it is better to use `to_date()` with a format model; or ANSI date literals). Supplying the column names as part of the statement can avoid misaligned data - e.g. `insert into staff (staff_id, title, firstname, lastname, hiredate) values ...`. Your table has lots of other columns though, so the insert you showed would complain about that first. Also check if there is a trigger on the table.

Comment: Yes. it is an id number. sorry this is my first assignment, i have never used sql before. INSERT INTO staff(id, title, firstname, lastname, hiredate) Values ('ST01', 'Mrs', 'Katie', 'Elswood', '06/10/1990'); Do you mean like this?

Comment: Yes, though with your real column names. The error suggests you were really supplying all the column values, with the salary in the wrong place perhaps - or possibly as a string literal, with the wrong group/decimal separators. (The error could also come from a trigger, but you'd see a larger error stack).

Comment: Thank you for your help alex. It appears that the format is set to MM/DD/YYYY. as one of the dates entered was 13/06/2015, it gave an error message. Im not sure how to fix this,but at least i now know the issue.

Comment: ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'MM/DD/YYYY'; should be DD/MM/YYYY, EASY FIX . THANKS

Comment: I think you're confusing yourself. The question says you want DD/MM/YYYY, but then you set the NLS value to MM/DD/YYYY. The date in your previous comment certainly looks like DD/MM; how do you know whether 06/10/1990 i the question is DD/MM or MM/DD? Hopefully they are all actually DD/MM, and you can just set that format. Or in your insert, use `to_date('06/10/1990','DD/MM/YYYY')` or a date literal like `DATE '1990-10-06'`. But this still has nothing to do with the ORA-01722 error you asked about...

Answer (score 2):

This is never a date issue. While inserting if you are not inserting all the values then oracle would throw out an error message. Hence please explicilty mention the column names for which you are going to insert the values.

```
Insert into staff(staff_id,title,first_name,surname,dob) values ('ST01','Mrs','Katie','Elswood','06/10/1990');
```